# How to insert a column vector using transpose of row vector in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode

I want to write `A=[Xtk Ytk .Xtk .Ytk]^T` in LaTeX. `^T` means that I want the transpose symbol "T" to come as superscript of the matrix. `Xtk` should appear as the variable `X` with subscript `t` and subsubscript `k`. Similarly for `Ytk`. Third entry, `.Xtk`, means that I want the `.` (dot) to come on top of `Xtk`, denoting velocity.

I want to know how these can be expressed in desired forms in LaTeX.

Comment: Hi! Do you mean `$A = [X_t^k, Y_t^k, \dot X_t^k, \dot Y_t^k]^T$` ?

Comment: It should be as equation because I want to number that.

Comment: Well, in all honesty, your question shows that you miss some basic stuff. If I can, I would like recommend you reading some book on LaTeX, there's a nice list of them here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11

Answer (score 12):

I agree with tohecz that you may need to do some basic reading regarding how to work with  LaTeX. I hope this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
     A=\begin{bmatrix}
         X_{t_{k}} &   Y_{t_{k}} & \dot{X}_{t_{k}}  &   \dot{Y}_{t_{k}}
        \end{bmatrix}^{T}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
     A=\begin{bmatrix}
         X_{t_{k}} \\
         Y_{t_{k}} \\
         \dot{X}_{t_{k}}\\
         \dot{Y}_{t_{k}}
        \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @zurr please mark this answer as such by klicking the check mark on the left. This will close this issue. Thanks.